Verification of Proof: Optimal Strategy for a Card Drawing Game
I'm working on the following probability problem and would like verification of my proof:
Problem Statement
Consider a deck of 52 regular playing cards, 26 red and 26 black, randomly shuffled. The cards are face down. Cards are drawn one at a time from the top of the deck and turned face up. At any point before the deck is exhausted, you must declare that you want the next card. If that next card is black, you win; otherwise, you lose.
The question is: Is there a strategy that gives a probability of winning strictly greater than 1/2?
My Proof Attempt
The decisions any strategy will make will fall into one of two cases:

When both red and black cards remain.
When either black or red cards remain.

We can calculate the probability of wining for each of them:

Probability of winning for decisions that are made when both red and
black cards remain:

There are 52!/26!*26! Arrangements of black and red cards. In all possible arrangements of 26 black and 26 red cards, for any given position, due to symmetry exactly half of the arrangements will have a black card in that position, and half will have a red card. This means that if after a number of cards if a strategy decides on the next card, the number of combinations where the next card is black equals the number of combinations where the next card is red. This means the overall probability of wining is 1/2 for such decisions.

Probability of winning for decisions that are made when either black or red cards remains:

We can only win this scenario only if black cards are remaining cards. The number of combinations whereby the last remaining cards are only black equals the number of combinations whereby the last remaining cards are only red. Therefore the probability of getting into a scenario where only black card remains equal 1/2 .
[Note that I'm referring to overall probability here not the probability in individual games which can increase or decrease. The result of making  such decisions is that they do not produce wining probability greater than 1/2 for the reasons provided.]
Thus, both types of decisions yields a probability no greater than 1/2. Therefore the overall wining probability for any strategy cannot be grater than 1/2.
My Question
My specific doubt is whether my reasoning in the second case is correct i.e that the probability of wining for decisions when only one color remains is indeed 1/2. Also does the conclusion I’ve derived from both cases (that no strategy can yield a probability greater than 1/2) logically follows or not.
Thank you in advance for your insights and corrections!

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

@Shaun I don't seem to be getting any responses. Should I delete and post this question again?

No. If you earn enough reputation points, you can place a bounty on it though.

You need at least 75 points to start a bounty.

@Shaun I have 57 Reputation, which means I will not be able to start a bounty.

Please see here.

@Shaun Moving the comments to chat may not have been helpful.  This proof attempt is not well worded even though the original assertion that all strategies involving making a choice before seeing the 52nd card give the same overall probability of success of $\frac12$.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4954814/proof-verification-no-strategy-exists-for-winning-with-probability-greater-than has the OP saying they want their "own unique solution to the problem" even though the problem has already appeared several times on this site with more convincing proofs.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4827620/winning-strategy-for-game-guessing-if-next-number-is-prime is one of the many duplicates of the original problem but not of this proof verification

It's not incumbent upon me to read all the comments and evaluate whether they have potential to help; rather, I skim through them to see if anything can be salvaged as stand-alone comments not encompassed in a conversation, @Henry.

I appreciate the feedback though, @Henry.
